# Flutter: CurveClipper with Container

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to curve a container using this code:

```
class CurveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    int curveHeight = 40;
    Offset controlPoint = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height + curveHeight);
    Offset endPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height - curveHeight);

    Path path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0, size.height - curveHeight)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(controlPoint.dx, controlPoint.dy, endPoint.dx, endPoint.dy)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Usage:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // The title text which will be shown on the action bar
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: CurveClipper(),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 200.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

However, this gets me this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHoj2.png)

But I want the curve to be at the top of the **container**, not the bottom. How can I achieve this?

Comment: "*But Ii want the curve to be at the top, not the bottom. How can I achieve this?"* - the red curve from your image **is** at the top

Comment: @pskink curve is at the bottom, There's an image.

Comment: @pskink, the image i posted has a curved container but at the bottom of the container, not the **top of the container** like i want

Comment: **top of the container** not top of the page

Comment: Your path logic is wrong.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya Obviously, hence the question.

Comment: post ss which you want to implement

Comment: https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one work for me
**ClipPath File**

```
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: ClipPathClass(),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

**ClipPathClass File**

```
    class ClipPathClass extends CustomClipper<Path> {
    @override
    Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0.0, size.height - (size.height * 6 / 8));

    var secondControlPoint = Offset(size.width / 2, 0);
    var secondPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height - (size.height * 6 / 8));
    path.quadraticBezierTo(secondControlPoint.dx, secondControlPoint.dy,
    secondPoint.dx, secondPoint.dy);

   path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
   path.lineTo(0, size.height);

   path.close();
   return path;
   }

   @override
   bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
   }
```

[image: This is the screenshot of the output]